# Ribbon Framework causes window with WS_VSCROLL to get a misaligned vertical scrollbar on Windows 7

Tags: ribbon

I've been trying to track down a problem in our application where a window created with a WS_VSCROLL style ends up with a misaligned vertical scrollbar on Windows 7 when the ribbon is enabled.

I've built the SimpleRibbon SDK sample with WS_VSCROLL on the main window styles and it exhibits the same behaviour. So it looks like some underlying problem rather than something in our code.

Interestingly, this only occurs on a hardware Windows 7 box running Aero Glass. A VM Windows 7 or an RDP session onto the Windows 7 machine does not have the problem!

I've uploaded a picture here - look at the top right corner of the window

http://www.house-on-the-hill.com/2010/capture.jpg

Any help appreciated

JF

Comment: I eventually worked around this problem by removing the WS_VSCROLL/WS_HSCROLL styles from the main window and creating my own vertical and horizontal scrollbar windows. Seemed to do the trick!